# Java: How can I fix this nested loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

Integer inputNum is read from input. For each number from 1 to inputNum, output the number followed by the number's value of hashtag characters ('#'). End each output with a newline.

Ex: If the input is 5, then the output is:

1#
2##
3###
4####
5#####

This is what I tried but the problem is that I don't know how to fix it so in the output, the character (in this case "#") is applied as many times as the number.

for instance, for input 5, my output was:

1#####
2#####
3#####
4#####
5#####

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopPatterns {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int inputNum;
      int i;
      int j;

      inputNum = scnr.nextInt();
  
      for (i = 1; i <= inputNum; ++i){
         System.out.print(i);
      for (j = inputNum; j >= 1; --j){
      System.out.print("#");
      }
      System.out.println();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript tag removed. This question and code have *nothing* to do with JavaScript programming.

Comment: In the inner loop, use `i` instead of `inputNum`. Unrelated: indenting your code makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner loop should count down from `i`. Like,

```
for (i = 1; i <= inputNum; ++i) {
    System.out.print(i);
    for (j = i; j >= 1; --j) {
        System.out.print("#");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, you will get following result: **1# 2## 3### 4####** 5#####

```
public class LoopPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int inputNum = s.nextInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=inputNum; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            for(int j=1; j<=i;j++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```